# What happens if I cancel deleting a folder?

Tags: windows-7, windows

I accidentally pressed delete on a 22GB folder with school work, but I pressed cancel immediately afterwards. There's nothing in the recycle bin and when I looked at the folder's size it was still 22GB.
Did some of the files actually get deleted?

Comment: Probably not but I don't understand why are you asking?!? You have the computer and you can check for yourself.

Comment: When you press delete it first scans the directory to find out how many files and how much it is going to be deleting. if you cancelled it quick enough it may not have deleted anything. Hard to know for sure though.

Answer (score 1):

If you cancelled the deletion process quickly, there is a chance that nothing got deleted, because for a 22 GB folder, the operating system first scans the folder to see how many files are into it. But nothing is for certain.

Next time be more careful.